# Build ZIP with Gradle and upload it for every commit using GitHub Actions

Tags: gradle, github-actions, intellij-plugin, gradlew

I have a GitHub repository for an IntelliJ plugin I wrote. I want a workflow that runs `./gradlew build` and upload the artifact on push.

Here's what I currently have:

```yaml
name: Make ZIP file

on:
  push:

jobs:
  make-zip:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      -
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      -
        name: Setup Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          distribution: zulu
          java-version: 17
      -
        name: Build with Gradle
        run: |
          chmod +x gradlew
          ./gradlew build
      -
        name: Upload ZIP
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: zip
          path: build/distributions/*
```

Here's the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'project'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'.
   > Cannot find a Java installation on your machine matching this tasks requirements: {languageVersion=17, vendor=JETBRAINS, implementation=vendor-specific} for LINUX on x86_64.
      > No locally installed toolchains match and toolchain download repositories have not been configured.
```

I get it: My plugin requires [JetBrainsRuntime](https://github.com/jetbrains/JetBrainsRuntime), which is not installed. The problem is *Setup Java* [doesn't support](https://github.com/actions/setup-java#supported-distributions) that distribution.

How do I make this work? I don't want to make a release for every single commit, and the ZIP file must be available for anyone who can `read` the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I needed to have these lines in my `settings.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins { 
    id("org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention") version "0.7.0" 
}
```

See also [this issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-platform-plugin-template/issues/447).